# SSIS not saving data to file even though it says i tis

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS package that runs file on my machine for 3 fiscal years. As soon as I promote it to the server and run it under a service account for 1 fiscal year it has issues.

It says it saves 23,000 rows to my file, but it doesn't. If I bring the date range down to 2 months it does save the information to the file (8600 rows).

The file is an xlsm .

any ideas why it is having this problem?

I have no warning or error messages when it is run.

Comment: What version of SSIS are you using? SSIS 2008, 2012,...?

Comment: If 8600 rows work, but 23000 rows don't, it means out of the range/memory. It will work if saved as flat file such as csv.

Comment: why would it run out of memory on a sever and not my machine? Also if I put it in a XLS file, it works fine. I am using 2010 that goes to a 2012 server.